# Return all results from left table when NULL present in right table and results of inner join when no null present in right table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi just wondering if this scenario is possible?

I have two tables and a relationship table to create a many to many relationships between the two tables. See the below tables for a simple representation;

```
| Security ID   | Security Group |
| 1             | Admin          |
| 2             | Basic          |

| Security ID   | Access ID      |
| 1             | NULL           |
| 2             | 1              |

| Function ID   | Function Code  |
| 1             | Search         | 
| 2             | Delete         |
```

What I want to achieve is while checking the relationship table I want to return all functions a user on a security group has access to. If the user is assigned to a security group that contains a NULL value in the relationship table then grant them access to all functions.

For instance, a user on the "Basic" security group would have access to the search function while a user on the "Admin" security group should have access to both Search and Delete.

The reason it is set up this way is because a user can have 0 to many security groups and the list of functions is very large requiring the use of a whitelist of functions you can access instead of a list of a blacklist of functions you can't access.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables' sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #G
(
    Security_ID INT,
    Security_Group      VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO #G
VALUES (1, 'Admin'), (2, 'Basic')

CREATE TABLE #A
(
    Security_ID INT,
    Access_ID   INT
)

INSERT INTO #A
VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1)

CREATE TABLE #F
(
    Function_ID INT,
    Function_CODE   VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO #F
VALUES (1, 'Search'), (2, 'Delete')
```

Query:

```
SELECT #G.Security_Group, #F.Function_CODE
FROM #G 
    JOIN #A ON #G.Security_ID = #A.Security_ID
    JOIN #F ON #F.Function_ID = #A.Access_ID OR #A.Access_ID IS NULL
```

Dropping the sample tables:

```
DROP TABLE #G
DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #F
```